# Detaching element and append without multiply in div

Tags: jquery, clone, detach

I want to detach or clone the a tag in my html.
I can't change the structure since i use a page builder.
It's like the a tag is being inserted two times if i have two elements. IF i have three elements, it's showing three times.

I have this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="element">
        <div class="container">
            <h4>Headline</h4>
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <div class="container">
            <h4>Headline</h4>
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="element">
        <a href="#"></a>
        <div class="container">
            <h4>Headline</h4>
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <a href="#"></a>
        <div class="container">
            <h4>Headline</h4>
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But i get this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="element">
        <a href="#"></a>
        <a href="#"></a>
        <div class="container">
            <h4>Headline</h4>
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <a href="#"></a>
        <a href="#"></a>
        <div class="container">
            <h4>Headline</h4>
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

// My jQuery

```
$('.element .container a').clone().prependTo('.element');
```

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read [ask] and edit question with a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's considered a bit discourteous when a question dumps large amounts of information as screenshots.  Please edit your question to reduce it to the smallest necessary code and output sample to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Updated version now. Sorry, new here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.element')` matches both of those divs, so each of the cloned links are being attached to both of them.

One way to avoid the unwanted duplicates is to be specific about which `.element` each of the cloned nodes should be attached to:

```js
$('.element .container a').each(function() {
  $(this).clone().prependTo(
    $(this).closest('.element')
  )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element">
    <div class="container">
      <h4>Headline</h4>
      <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="container">
      <h4>Headline</h4>
      <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've tried this before, but it wasn't correct. You saved me pal :)

Comment: No worries, glad I could help!